# Why KafkaMessageSource generates messages without Id?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am using an @InboundChannelAdapter to consume messages from Kafka. The messages produced by KafkaMessageSource do not have an Id, which makes it impossible to insert them in a channel backed by JdbcChannelMessageStore.

Can this behavior be configured?

I tried going through a messageTransformer to build a new message from the original one, but again no Id is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom `MessagingMessageConverter` to the source:

```java
/**
 * Set the message converter to replace the default
 * {@link MessagingMessageConverter}.
 * @param messageConverter the converter.
 */
public void setMessageConverter(RecordMessageConverter messageConverter) {
    this.messageConverter = messageConverter;
}
```

and call `setGenerateMessageId(true)` (and, optionally `setGenerateTimestamp`) on the converter.